# Rapid easy question on cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

If a cyclic group $C=\langle c\rangle$ has an involution $z$, then

1. $C$ is finite
2. $C$ has even order
3. the involution is unique

If $C$ was not finite, then it must be isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z,+)$ which has no element $a\neq0$ s.t. $a+a=2a=0$, hence $C$ must be finite.

Then $C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for some $n$. And here $2a=0$ is true iff $n$ is even.

Finally I noticed that an involution must be $z=c^{\frac n2}$, so it's necessarely unique.

Am I right?
Thank you all.

Comment: An involution $z$ on a set (or group or anything) $C$ is a function (or homomorphism or whatever kind of map is appropriate) with the property that $z(z(c)) = c$ for all $c \in C$. A *nontrivial* involution is an involution that is not the identity map (the identity map is *always* an involution). Either you are using the wrong word, or you have the definition wrong. I think you are also mixing up the additive group of elements in $\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z}$ with the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl It's common, in group theory, to call *involution* an element $z$ such that $z\ne1$ and $z^2=1$.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, that interpretation makes sense. The wording "C has an involution" makes it sound like he wants an involution *acting on* $C$, rather than one that is an element of $C$, and I failed to come up with a different reading.

Comment: @Hurkyl Any abelian group, except for two cases, has a non trivial involutive automorphism, that is, taking the inverse, which would make the problem quite unsensical.

Comment: @egreg: ... thus my comment.

Comment: Yes guys, by "$C$ has an involution" I meant "there exists an involution of an element of the group $C$"; and an element of a group is an involution if it has order $2$ without being the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that, by *involution* in a (multiplicative) group $G$, you mean an element $g\in G$ such that $g^2=1$ and $g\ne 1$.

You're correct in your conclusions, but I would show the details in a better form.

Lagrange's theorem implies that a finite group with an involution has even order. So, in your case, $C$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(2k)\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k>0$.

Cauchy's theorem, on the other hand, implies that any finite group with even order has at least an involution.

Now, passing to additive notation, your involution will be an element $z+2k\mathbb{Z}$ with $0<z<2k$ and
$$
2z\in 2k\mathbb{Z}.
$$
This means $z\in k\mathbb{Z}$, so $z=ky$. Then from $0<ky<2k$ you conclude that $0<y<2$, which leaves little to imagination. `;-)`